# Adding TextView dynamically under the relativeLayout

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZeqH.png)how can i add multiple TextView and their inside relative layout dynamically which is already created? Also I have to call the values of those text boxes from database sqlite.

public class DownloadPackagesActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
DBHelper dbHelper;
String newFolder = "";
int SId = 1;
TextView subjects;
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
String FilePart = "";

DownloadManager dManager;
long did;
// private static String file_url = "http://mobileteacher.in/audio/demo/2725.mp3";
String urlString ="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_packages);
    // Get DownloadManager instance
    dManager = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    subjects = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subjects);
    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPackage);
    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // Add textview
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    try{
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    String myPath = dbHelper.DB_PATH + DBHelper.DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from DownloadSubject", null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        categories.add(c.getString(1));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, categories);
    dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
    showPart();
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    SId = position + 1;
    showPart();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
public void showPart()
{
    int j=1;
    int ii=0;
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    try{
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);
    stk.removeAllViews();
    String myPath = dbHelper.DB_PATH + DBHelper.DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Cursor c;
    if (SId==8 || SId==9)
    {
        c = db.rawQuery("select * from DownloadSubject", null);
    }
    else
    {
        c = db.rawQuery("select * from DownloadSubject where Id = '"+ SId +"'", null);
    }
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        subjects.clearComposingText();


        String[] part = c.getString(2).split(",");
        for(int i = 0;i<part.length;i++)
        {

            TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            button.setText(part[i] +"\u00A0 \u00A0 \u00A0 \u00A0 Download");
            button.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            button.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            button.setOnClickListener(downloads());
            button.setId(i);
            // button.setHint(part[i]);
            tr1.addView(button);
            stk.addView(tr1);
        }
        stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);
        int N = 1;
        TextView[] TextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;
        // for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        //if(ii!=0) {
        // subjects.setText(c.getString(j));
        // Toast.makeText(this, c.getString(j), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        // save a reference to the textview for later
        // TextViews[j] = TextView;
        //}
        if(ii==0)
        {
            subjects.setText(c.getString(j));
            ii=ii+1;
        }
        else
        {
            final TextView TextView = new TextView(this);
            TextView.setText(c.getString(j));
            TextView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TextView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
            TextView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
            TextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
            // add the textview to the layout
            stk.addView(TextView);
        }

    }
}
public String part;
View.OnClickListener downloads()
{
    return new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Button b1 = (Button)v;
            //int i  = b1.getId();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ide = " + i,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            part ="";
            TextView subjects = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subjects);
            if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("Modern History (500 MB)"))
            {
                part = "modern_history";
            }
            else if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("Polity (250 MB)"))
            {
                part = "polity";
            }
            else if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("Economy (100 MB)"))
            {
                part = "economy";
            }
            else if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("Ancient History (500 MB)"))
            {
                part = "ancient_history";
            }
            else if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("English Grammar (500 MB)"))
            {
                part = "english_grammar";
            }
            else if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("Vocabulary (560 MB)"))
            {
                part = "vocabulary";
            }
            else if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("Maths (100 MB)"))
            {
                part = "maths";
            }
            else if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("One Day Complete(Vol.1(2GB))"))
            {
                part = "oneday_complete";
            }
            else if(subjects.getText().toString().equals("Civil Complete (Vol.1 (2GB))"))
            {
                part = "civil_complete" ;
            }

            newFolder = "/voice";
            subjects = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subjects);
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + newFolder);
            //File f = new File(myNewFolder);
            myNewFolder.mkdir();

            Button b = (Button)v;
            FilePart  = b.getText().toString();
            String RemoveSpace = FilePart.split("\u00A0")[0].replace(" ","");
            try {
                urlString = "http://mobileteacher.in/DealerPackage/" + part + "/" + RemoveSpace + ".zip";
                downloadFile();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Connect Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
public void downloadFile() {
    // String urlString = "http://mobileteacher.in/audio/demo/2725.mp3";
    if (!urlString.equals("")) {
        try {
            // Get file name from the url
            String fileName = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            // Create Download Request object
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse((urlString)));
            // Display download progress and status message in notification bar
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            // Set description to display in notification
            // request.setDescription("Download " + fileName + " from " + urlString);
            request.setDescription("Download " + fileName + " from mobileteacher.in");
            // Set title
            request.setTitle("Mobile Teacher");
            // Set destination location for the downloaded file
            request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/voice/"+fileName.split("\u00A0")[0].replace(" ","")));
            // Download the file if the Download manager is ready
            did = dManager.enqueue(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
// BroadcastReceiver to receive intent broadcast by DownloadManager
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
        q.setFilterById(did);
        Cursor cursor = dManager.query(q);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String message = "";
            int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
            if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                message = "Download successful";
            } else if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED) {
                message = "Download failed";
            }
            //query.setText(message);
        }
    }
};

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Register the receiver to receive an intent when download complete
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
    registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, intentFilter);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    // Unregister the receiver
    unregisterReceiver(downloadReceiver);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_download_packages, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void back(View view)
{
    finish();
}
public void Create(View view)
{
    String newFolder = "/voice";
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myNewFolder = new File(ext[enter image description here][1]StorageDirectory + newFolder);
    myNewFolder.mkdir();
}
```

}

this is the image

Comment: Instead of "multiple TextView", use a ListView. Or a RecyclerView.

Comment: I have multiple subject and its file to download. in spinnerview i have crated the subjects to be selected and when user clicks all the parts of subjects appears in tablelaout for download. Now i want to select a package of all subjects inside it and when a user select this particular package the name of subject along with its parts should be appear in that layout.

Comment: <TableLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/chart"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/tbl"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:background="@color/adds_text"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:backgroundTintMode="screen">
                </TableLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create relative layout object from it layout id, then you can add it as below

```
relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.yourRelativeLayoutId);
relativeLayout.addView(yourView);
```

Answer (score 0):

appending a textview to relativelayout is pretty simple.
just use

```
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
textview.setText("Text");
relativelayoutobject.addView(textview);
```

to setup the position use
`textview.setLayoutParams(thelayoutparams)`

But if you use big database, please, use 'TableLayout' instead of your method due to performance reasons.

Comment: subjects=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.subjects);
            TableLayout TLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);

            final TextView[] TextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                final TextView TextView = new TextView(this);
                TextView.setText(c.getString(j));
                // add the textview to the layout
                TLayout.addView(TextView);
                // save a reference to the textview for later
                TextViews[i] = TextView;
            }

Comment: i meant that the root layout was relative but i had to use inside the tablelaout, now i have created textviews but i want to call the data related to those textviews from database

Comment: Ok. Found. But it is really difficult to read your post. write your code inside the question not in comments to make your ideas easy to undestand. Nevertheless, have you found the solution of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Listview or recyclerview is best for practice but as you want to use textview, you can use like this in your code:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout =
        (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Hey, I am TextView");

    relativeLayout.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define relative layout in your xml layout. Add multiple textview programmatic ally like this-

```
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        //use a for loop to define multiple textView in RelativeLayout
        //length is no. of textView you required
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(relativeLayout.getContext());
            tv.setText("Text from sqlite database");
            tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            relativeLayout.addView(tv);
        }
```

Comment: thyank you very mutch

Comment: yes but i still have a problem with retrieving data from sqlite for those textviews

Comment: post your code that that is accessing data from database